# The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System' - Creating AWS Lambda function

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am trying to create an AWS Lambda function in .NET Core 1.0 using Visual Studio AWS Toolkit. I have created an empty Lambda function and attempted adding the required assemblies to work with SQL Server databases (I have other projects where I've been able to do this successfully).

For some reason even after adding the required packages, I can't get System.Data.SqlClient to resolve. It says the type 'Data' does not exist in 'System'. This usually means I haven't added the right assembly. But I have! I have both System.Data.Common 4.3.0 and System.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0. What am I doing wrong? Here is the Nuget output so you can see I've added them:

```
PM> install-package System.Data.Common -version 4.3.0
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz/system.data.common/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz/system.data.common/index.json 906ms
Restoring packages for C:\LambdaBuild\LambdaProcessBounce\LambdaProcessBounce\LambdaProcessBounce\LambdaProcessBounce.csproj...
Installing NuGet package System.Data.Common 4.3.0.
Committing restore...
Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\LambdaBuild\LambdaProcessBounce\LambdaProcessBounce\LambdaProcessBounce\obj\project.assets.json
Restore completed in 1.58 sec for C:\LambdaBuild\LambdaProcessBounce\LambdaProcessBounce\LambdaProcessBounce\LambdaProcessBounce.csproj.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 1.0.2' from LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.NETCore.Targets 1.0.3' from LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully uninstalled 'System.Collections 4.0.11' from LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully uninstalled 'System.Globalization 4.0.11' from LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully uninstalled 'System.IO 4.1.0' from LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully uninstalled 'System.Reflection 4.1.0' from LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully uninstalled 'System.Reflection.Primitives 4.0.1' from LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully uninstalled 'System.Resources.ResourceManager 4.0.1' from LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully uninstalled 'System.Runtime 4.1.0' from LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully uninstalled 'System.Runtime.Extensions 4.1.0' from LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully uninstalled 'System.Text.Encoding 4.0.11' from LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully uninstalled 'System.Text.RegularExpressions 4.1.0' from LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully uninstalled 'System.Threading 4.0.11' from LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully uninstalled 'System.Threading.Tasks 4.0.11' from LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 1.1.0' to LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.NETCore.Targets 1.1.0' to LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully installed 'System.Collections 4.3.0' to LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully installed 'System.Data.Common 4.3.0' to LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully installed 'System.Globalization 4.3.0' to LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully installed 'System.IO 4.3.0' to LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully installed 'System.Reflection 4.3.0' to LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully installed 'System.Reflection.Primitives 4.3.0' to LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully installed 'System.Resources.ResourceManager 4.3.0' to LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully installed 'System.Runtime 4.3.0' to LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully installed 'System.Runtime.Extensions 4.3.0' to LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully installed 'System.Text.Encoding 4.3.0' to LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully installed 'System.Text.RegularExpressions 4.3.0' to LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully installed 'System.Threading 4.3.0' to LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully installed 'System.Threading.Tasks 4.3.0' to LambdaProcessBounce
Executing nuget actions took 1.14 sec
Time Elapsed: 00:00:04.2014899
PM> install-package System.Data.SqlClient -version 4.1.0
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz/system.data.sqlclient/index.json
  OK https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz/system.data.sqlclient/index.json 878ms
Restoring packages for C:\LambdaBuild\LambdaProcessBounce\LambdaProcessBounce\LambdaProcessBounce\LambdaProcessBounce.csproj...
Installing NuGet package System.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0.
Committing restore...
Writing lock file to disk. Path: C:\LambdaBuild\LambdaProcessBounce\LambdaProcessBounce\LambdaProcessBounce\obj\project.assets.json
Restore completed in 1.15 sec for C:\LambdaBuild\LambdaProcessBounce\LambdaProcessBounce\LambdaProcessBounce\LambdaProcessBounce.csproj.
Successfully installed 'runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni 4.0.0' to LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully installed 'runtime.win7-x64.runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni 4.0.1' to LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully installed 'runtime.win7-x86.runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni 4.0.1' to LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully installed 'System.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0' to LambdaProcessBounce
Successfully installed 'System.IO.Pipes 4.0.0' to LambdaProcessBounce
Executing nuget actions took 1.76 sec
Time Elapsed: 00:00:04.0019743
PM>
```

Comment: I have same issue, did you figure it out?

Comment: Sorry - still waiting on help on this one. I got inconsistent results by adding earlier versions of system.data.sqlclient, and when I say inconsistent I mean using the same version of Visual Studio, one lambda function compiled fine, yet another didn't. It's all a bit confusing..... it shouldn't be this difficult.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I was running VS2015 with .NET Core 1.0.

Run the following under the Nuget Package console.

```
Install-Package System.Data.SqlClient -Version 4.1.0
```

Note, it might not work with other versions. I saw one blog that where 4.1 worked for them, but not higher ones. It might depend on which version of .NET Core you are using.

Comment: Thanks Neal - I will check this out and report back.